# Why my api request returns an empty object?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

So I use Google Books API in my application, and i make a request do display data in console, but for some reason it returns an empty object, instead of array of books.

Javascript code:

```
const API_KEY = 'key=<API-KEY>';
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/';
const API_URL = BASE_URL + 'volumes?q=subject:fiction' + API_KEY;

getBooks(API_URL);

function getBooks(url){
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data =>{
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Console in browser:

[image]

Edit:
So I added '&' in the url and it changed, but now it gives 403 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Maybe I got the wrong key? I got it from Google Books credentials, so I thought it should've worked.

Comment: are you sure you have any books that the api should return?

Comment: Are you sure you want to post your API key here for anyone to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `&` sign between the query params, so you need to change

```js
const API_URL = BASE_URL + 'volumes?q=subject:fiction' + API_KEY;
```

to

```js
const API_URL = BASE_URL + 'volumes?q=subject:fiction&' + API_KEY;
```

And also revoke this API Key

Answer (score 1):

You sent the key as part of the q value because you forgot an '&'.

```
const API_URL = BASE_URL + 'volumes?q=subject:fiction&' + API_KEY;
```

Comment: thank you! i'm new to working with api, so i didn't know about that
but now it gives 403 error that has something to do with android, which i added in the post